# how to remove arrow in TableViewCell in Xcode Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, storyboard

I want to remove this arrow in picture bellow on XCode storyboard design when I chose master-detail application.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the arrow (Table cell accessory) select the corresponding prototype cell and change the Accessory view to `None` in attribute inspector.

See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, select your cell. Then in the attributes inspector change the accessory value to `None`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set it in code by:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
```